I can't turn on Bluetooth in Ubuntu
I just installed Ubuntu. I cant turn on Bluetooth on my unbuntu.
My bluetooth setting

Someone tell me run this command:
echo 'clearing dmesg...';
sudo dmesg -c && clear;
DEVICE=$(rfkill list all | grep -o 'hci*.');
sudo hciconfig ${DEVICE} down;
sudo rmmod btusb;
sudo service bluetooth disable;

sudo modprobe btusb;
sudo hciconfig ${DEVICE} up;
sudo service bluetooth enable;
echo '\n~~rfkill:';
rfkill unblock bluetooth;
rfkill list all;
echo "\n~~~DMESG:";
sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth;
echo '\n~~~bluetooth status:';
sudo service bluetooth status;

echo '\n~~~if failed try manually:';
bluetoothctl power on;
bluetoothctl devices;
read DEVICE_TO_CONNECT;
bluetoothctl connect ${DEVICE_TO_CONNECT}
echo "~~~\nFINISH UP:\n~~~~run bluetoothctl;\n~~~~~power on && devices && connect";

Here is the result:
Usage: /etc/init.d/bluetooth {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)
Usage: /etc/init.d/bluetooth {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}
\n~~rfkill:
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
\n~~~DMESG:
[  751.882068] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110
[  753.929929] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x0c03 failed: -110
\n~~~bluetooth status:
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset>
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-07-16 21:51:00 +07; 12min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 842 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18872)
     Memory: 2.8M (peak: 3.1M)
        CPU: 63ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─842 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jul 16 21:51:00 nhphan-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Started bluetooth.servic>
Jul 16 21:51:00 nhphan-System-Product-Name bluetoothd[842]: Starting SDP server
Jul 16 21:51:00 nhphan-System-Product-Name bluetoothd[842]: src/plugin.c:plugin>
Jul 16 21:51:00 nhphan-System-Product-Name bluetoothd[842]: profiles/audio/micp>
Jul 16 21:51:00 nhphan-System-Product-Name bluetoothd[842]: src/plugin.c:plugin>
Jul 16 21:51:00 nhphan-System-Product-Name bluetoothd[842]: src/plugin.c:plugin>
Jul 16 21:51:00 nhphan-System-Product-Name bluetoothd[842]: src/plugin.c:plugin>
Jul 16 21:51:00 nhphan-System-Product-Name bluetoothd[842]: src/plugin.c:plugin>
Jul 16 21:51:00 nhphan-System-Product-Name bluetoothd[842]: src/plugin.c:plugin>
Jul 16 21:51:00 nhphan-System-Product-Name bluetoothd[842]: Bluetooth managemen>


That's a good start but there are a bunch of errors in the usage. Can you add the following: Ubuntu version. Output of rfkill list all and sudo modprobe btusb

Also use sudo service bluetooth stop and sudo service bluetooth start instead of disable and enable.

Please edit to include results from terminal for lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'
